# Automatically dial the default Internet connection at Windows startup

Tags: windows-7, dial-up

How can I configure Windows 7 to automatically dial the default dial-up Internet connection as soon as a user logs in?

I use a dial-up connection for accessing the Internet, and I don't want to dial everytime I log in to Windows.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A shortcut in the Start menu didn't work for me but this did:

http://www.recipester.org/Recipe:Make_ADSL_auto-connect_on_PC_startup_28846102

In case that link goes bad:

Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Schedule Tasks

Create basic task... -> When I logon -> Start a program: "c:\Windows\System32\rasphone.exe" arguments: "-d NetworkConnection" where NetworkConnection is replaced by the name of your network connection.

If you don't know the name, run "rasphone" from the Start button and look at the list.  You must put the name in quotes if there's a space in it.  To test if it works, you can test it from the command-line.

You should also configure the connection to not require name and password when connecting so that it'll connect when you're away from the computer.  To do that, first configure the connection to require name/password.  Next disconnect and reconnect.  In the connect screen, enter name and password and check the "remember password" option, for everyone.  Now connect and that will save the "remember password" option.  Finally, go back to the properties and remove the "require name/password" option.

Comment: +1 It worked on XP too. Thanks! I wonder why the shortcut method doesn't work sometimes and what is actually happening when that shortcut is found there

Comment: Maybe it's a timing thing with the shortcut?  On my computer, I need the dialer to run later in the boot-up process.

Comment: In my pc, creating shortcut in *All User* startup folder did not work. But when I tried my account's startup folder, It worked like a charm. :-)

Comment: How do you configure the connection to "not require username & password" so that there is no prompting, on Windows 10?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to go to the window where it lists all your dial up networking connections and click the automatically connect check box, followed by connect... You can cancel straight away but clicking connect saves the changes.

Next, click on the start menu then expand "all programs", right click the startup group and choose open.

Lastly, drag a shortcut from dial up networking to the startup group and it should launch and automatically connect every time you log on.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

1. Create a shortcut on the desktop
2. In the location type:

   ```
   rasphone.exe -d nameofyourconnection
   ```

   Mine is:

   ```
   rasphone.exe -d haMid
   ```
3. Type the name of the shortcut. You can put anything here. Click Finish/OK.

---

If you want your shortcut icon to have no text so it seems like a picture on your desktop (in short, remove the icon text): right-click the icon and select rename. Press Alt+255 on your keyboard.

Comment: +1 cool alt+seq trick from old days :) who would think of that ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect automatically ("Dialup OR Dial Up") then use this four-step method:

1. make the properties of the connection like this one:-
2. Use the program named `netsnsor` to download it and to know how to use it:
3. Command syntax (Rasdial)
4. From the Program setup, click Autostart

See also *[Dial up Automatic - NetSnsor.mp4](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zkmRCcpvY7w)* (YouTube video, 8 min 32 sec).

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use the registry

```
HKEY_USERS\SomeUserId\Software\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
NetworkConnect = "c:\windows\system32\rasphone "-d" "[Your network name]""
```

Then, maybe you could do it for all users, the admin only, or for the guest group that you may
have otherwise disable network settings for?