# Connect PPPoE broadband connection on boot on Windows 7

Tags: networking, boot, pppoe

I got a static IP PPPoE connection from my ISP provider, and I am running a VNC server on it, and needs to connect a PPPoE connection on boot.

Is there a solution to that?

Answer (score 4):

Follow these steps:

1. Go to Start menu and type in the search field ***ncpa.cpl*** and hit enter
2. Right click your PPPoE Internet Connection and select ***Properties***
3. Go to ***Options*** tab and uncheck ***Prompt for name and password, certificate, etc.***, and set ***Redial attempts*** to as many as you want, and also set ***Time between redial attempts*** to, say, ***3 seconds*** and then click OK

Make sure your PPPoE connection is set to Default by going to **Control Panel**->**Network and Sharing Center**->**Change Adapter Settings** and right-clicking on this internet connection and selecting ***Set as Default Connection***

Now, type in the start menu search field ***inetcpl.cpl*** and hit enter and go to ***Connections*** tab.

- Select your PPPoE connection
- Select ***Dial whenever a network connection is not present***.
- Click ***Set default*** if button is active and click OK.

Now, just log off and and log in. The connection should be dialed automatically.

EDIT: Right-click on ***All Programs*** in **Start** menu and click **Open**. Now, open **Programs** folder and double-click on **Startup** folder. Type in ***ncpa.cpl*** in **Start** menu search field and hit enter. Just drag-and-drop your pppoes internet connection into this **Startup** folder. Do log-off, log-in.

Comment: I will try as soon as Windows Update finished. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: It seems to do nothing on boot, I doesn't even connect on login. Is there a script or startup item I can do?

Comment: Added another possible solution. Just try this.

Comment: Yes, that doesn't work either. I've tried that. It connects only when logged in, not on boot. BTW, I am not using 7 strictly, 2008 R2.

Comment: You are saying <needs to connect a PPPoE connection on boot

Comment: Yes, on boot, even when no user has logged in

Comment: I think it is possible only using some network device like router or modem if your connection is ADSL.

Comment: Don't think so. That would be very lame. I keep digging, and I come back when I've found something.

Comment: "Dial whenever a network connection is not present" is no more in windows 7, they say it was removed with ie 11, any other ideas ? ... until win7/ie11 yours was the solution I knew about it too

Comment: @THESorcerer: Follow [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/ba0dd952-cd69-422c-a983-363d0bad6b55/where-did-the-dial-whenever-a-network-connection-is-not-present-setting-go?forum=ieitprocurrentver) link. You need to edit the registry setting for this. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

On any Windows 7 this simple procedure should work:

- Start.
- Open startup folder.
- Create new text document.
- Type `Start Rasdial connectionname username password` - e.g: `Start rasdial cucunet john john123`.
- Change extension to `BAT` (delete `.txt` extension and replace with `.bat`).

enjoy!

I don't recommend to use `Broadband Connection` as the connection name; just rename your connection to a one word name like `Broadband` or `Mynet` or `RDS` :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this: [Automatically dial the default Internet connection at Windows startup](https://superuser.com/questions/80217/automatically-dial-the-default-internet-connection-at-windows-startup)

With the slight modification that do not set "When I logon", but set "At system startup".

- You still need to disable "prompt for name and password" as "om sai" said.